# ContentTools - Clicking in the link tool's dialog focuses on background element, and not on its input?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, wysiwyg, content-tools

I'm using [ContentTools](https://getcontenttools.com/) in a [Bootstrap modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/modal/). When I select some text and click the hyperlink tool, the dialog to enter the link pops up, but immediately gives focus to an element in the background (in this case, the modal close button, but when I remove it, it focuses on the first input in the form, etc). This makes it impossible to type in the dialog to create a link.

Any pointers? Not a JS wiz, but from a peek at the ContentTools source, it seems to set up an event handler to grab the click event and give focus to the dialog's input, and I'm assuming that's getting borked somewhere...

[Here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwiCi.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

For [anyone who finds this later](https://xkcd.com/979/), the issue was that Bootstrap's modals maintain focus and re-capture it anytime it is given to an element in the background. Since ContentTools appends itself to the end of the DOM (after my modal), it is in the "background" as far as bootstrap is concerned. Buttons in ContentTools work because they register as click events, but anytime you try to click in an input, it gains focus, and Bootstrap returns focus to the modal.

My solution was to modify the ContentTools source to instead append itself to the end of my modal `<div>`, and now it's entirely contained within the modal--Bootstrap has no focus issues.